# Why does json result cut my string into characters?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im having problems with gallery: http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumbnail-slider-demo-3

Below is the Ajax code pulling picture file names via php from server. The shitty code when it gets the picture file names it cuts them into separate characters.

This is the data result I get, json format (340 characters long!):

```
["img\/hardside\/1.jpg","img\/hardside\/10.jpg","img\/hardside\/11.jpg","img\/hardside\/12.jpg","img\/hardside\/2.jpg","img\/hardside\/3.jpg","img\/hardside\/32.jpg","img\/hardside\/4.jpg","img\/hardside\/41.jpg","img\/hardside\/5.jpg","img\/hardside\/6.jpg","img\/hardside\/7.jpg","img\/hardside\/8.jpg","img\/hardside\/9.jpg"]
```

But the Javascript instead of putting them as 1 string in thumbs section it cuts them to pieces are creates a gallery with 340 pictures (same as returned number of data characters)! How do I tell this piece of ... code... to treate returned data as a whole string and not an array of characters? As you can see below, I tried to use typecasting .toString() - doesn't work. I tried to use for loop to combine characters into one string, still doesn't work. How to do it? I need the data picture json result as one string not 340 single characters.

```
 $.ajax({
          type: "post", 
          url: "getfiles.php?dirname="+dirname, 
          //data: dirname,
          enctype: "application/json", 
          success: function(data) { 
            //alert(data); 
            var imgarr = '';
            for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ 
                imgarr = imgarr + data[i];
                //imgarr.concat(data[i]);
                //let imgarr = + data[i];
                //alert(data[i]);
              }
            //alert(imgarr);
            var imgarrf = imgarr.toString();
            $("#thumbsliderdiv0").imageSlider({ //initialize slider
                        'thumbs': String(imgarrf),
                //["img\/hardside\/1.jpg","img\/hardside\/10.jpg","img\/hardside\/11.jpg","img\/hardside\/12.jpg","img\/hardside\/2.jpg","img\/hardside\/3.jpg","img\/hardside\/32.jpg","img\/hardside\/4.jpg","img\/hardside\/41.jpg","img\/hardside\/5.jpg","img\/hardside\/6.jpg","img\/hardside\/7.jpg","img\/hardside\/8.jpg","img\/hardside\/9.jpg"],//data,
                        'auto_scroll':true,
                        'auto_scroll_speed':4500,
                        'stop_after': 2, //stop after x cycles? Set to 0 to disable.
                        'canvas_width':screen.width*0.66,
                        'canvas_height':600 // <-- No comma after last option
                    })
          } 
        });
```

I tried typecasting, i tried for loop, didn't work.

Comment: so `data` is a string (a JSON string) ... simply use `JSON.parse(data)` - the result will be an array

Comment: note, it's not JSON that is "cutting" your result into characters, it's your code that does that

Comment: Jaromanda X probably right! But which part? Here you have the complete code: http://www.menucool.com/slider/thumbnail-slider-demo-3

Comment: and here: http://www.menucool.com/jquery-slider

Comment: and how to fix it? because if I just put string in comments below instead of imgarrf variable it works fine. There is something here 'thumbs': String(imgarrf) that is cutting the string to characters. But what it is?

Comment: actually you are right! Json.Parse solved the problem! Thanks.

Comment: *simply use JSON.parse(data) - the result will be an array*